# Using one-hot encoded features along with continuous-valued features?

Tags: categorical-data, predictive-models, prediction, continuous-data, categorical-encoding

The task I wanted to do is a prediction task where most of the features are continuous numbers and some of the features are one-hot encoded. I am training a neural network and I wondered that, is it sensible from a methodological perspective? If not, can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Check for integers - if the continuous data happen to be integers, then they may be confused with categorical. Normalising the continuous data will reduce the risk of this error.

Consider adding binning and bagging, dealing with outliers, transform skewed datasets, PCA/factor analysis etc

Deal with time-series data

After doing the above, reducing the number of features can actually improve NN results.